# Blockchain trying to add key / value to the transacton dictionary to create a blockchain

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, blockchain

Quick question inside my code I am generating a Key Error from lines 14-21. When I try to insert an input function inside the transaction dictionary I receive a Key error.  My question is how can I insert these values into my dictionary to create a blockchain? My Objective is to introduce a while loop that will put blocks on a blockchain. For the data element of each block I have to make a dictionary that holds the following keys\values: sender, receiver, money_amount. After I gather these values from the user input. My while loop should keep asking for values until it's told to stop. Once I gather all of my values, I have to validate the blockchain to ensure it's good.

```
import hashlib
import json
from time import time 

class Block():
    def __init__(self, nonce, tstamp, transaction, prevhash=''):
        self.nonce = nonce
        self.tstamp = time()
        self.transaction = {}
        self.prevhash = prevhash
        self.hash = self.calhash()
        self.chain = []
        
        while True:
            self.sender = input("Sender:\n")
            self.transaction[self.sender]
            self.reciever = input("Receiver\n")
            self.transaction[self.reciever]
            self.amount = input("money_amt: \n")
            self.transaction[self.amount]
            break

    def calhash(self):
        block_string = json.dumps({"nonce": self.nonce, " tstamp": self.tstamp, " transaction": self.transaction, " prevhash": self.prevhash}, sort_keys=True).encode()
        return hashlib.sha256(block_string).hexdigest()

    def __str__(self):
        string= " nonce:" + " " + str(self.nonce) + "\n"
        string += " tstamp:" + " " + str(self.tstamp) + "\n"
        string += " transaction:" + " " + str(self.transaction) + "\n"
        string += " prevhash:" + " " + str(self.prevhash) + "\n"
        string += " hash:" + " " + str(self.hash) + "\n"

        return string 

    def printHashes(self):
        print("prevhash", self.prevhash)
        print("hash", self.hash)


class Blockchain():
    def __init__(self):
        self.chain=[self.generateGenesisBlock(),]
        
    def generateGenesisBlock(self):
        return Block(0, "" ," ", " ")

    def getLastBlock(self):
        return self.chain[-1]

    def addBlock(self, new_block):
        new_block.prevhash=self.getLastBlock().hash
        new_block.hash=new_block.calhash()
        self.chain.append(new_block)

    def isChainValid(self):
        for i in range(1, len(self.chain)):
            prevb=self.chain[i-1]
            currb=self.chain[i]
            if(currb.hash != currb.calhash()):
                print("invalid block")
                return False
            if(currb.prevhash != prevb.hash):
                print("invalid chain")
                return False
            return True


BTC = Blockchain()
BTC.addBlock(Block(1, " ", "Sender: Luke Reciepent: James Amount: 220", " "))

for b in BTC.chain:
    print(b)
print(BTC.isChainValid())
```

Comment: What do lines 16, 18, 20 are supposed to do? No variable is assigned, no function is called, no I/O.

Comment: "self.transaction[self.sender]" is not goof you shoud assign something to it "self.transaction[self.sender]=..."

Answer (score 0):

I am newer to python but reading up on your error, one solution that I was able to come up with is using .get() method to return either the value found at the specified key or a default value. So for your specific issue:

```
    while True:
        self.sender = input("Sender:\n")
        self.transaction.get(self.sender)
        self.reciever = input("Receiver\n")
        self.transaction.get(self.reciever)
        self.amount = input("money_amt: \n")
        self.transaction.get(self.amount)
        break
```

Comment: `.get` functions return `None`.